# OPENvpn server traffic not use sshuttle

Tags: server, vpn, openvpn

I have 2 servers (server A and server B). I installed Openvpn on server A and I use OPENVPN CONNECT on my laptop and iphone (iOS) and everything is OK. Now when I check my IP in the laptop and iOS they show SERVER A s IP. Good.

I installed sshuttle on server A and after running:

```
sshuttle --dns -D -r root@SERVER_B_IP
```

After entering the password, now my IP is  SERVER B s IP and everything is fine.

When I use openvpn connect on the PC or iOS my IP still is SERVER A IP. I need to all my traffic in laptop and iOS to use server B (like server A after using sshuttle).

How do I do this?

Server A is Ubuntu and Server B is centos. All configs (open vpn and sshuttle) are default.